# unencrypted, password-free VNC connection

Tags: debian, vnc, administrator, vncserver, debian-jessie

I setup conferences twice a year where users come to learn a program that we have created. I have a powerful laptop (running Debian Jessie) and a router to create a local network and I'd like to give the users access to the laptop via VNC from their computers so they all work with a similar environment.

My question is: how can I create an unencrypted, password-free VNC server on the laptop so that all the users have to do is connect to 192.168.X.X:59XX and be able to visualize and function in the desktop environment on the server?

I have already:

1. installed `x11vnc`
2. modified `/etc/inetd.conf` with the script to run when a connection is made to a given port.

   1. The script launches `x11vnc` with: `x11vnc -inetd -q -display WAIT:cmd=FINDCREATEDISPLAY-Xvfb.xdmcp`
3. opened all connections via `iptables`

yet, I can only connect via VNC to the port associated with a user that is **currently logged in** on the server itself (i.e., I open the laptop, log in, then I can open a VNC connection to the port associated with my account in `/etc/inetd.conf`). All other VNC connections show only a blank screen. My guess is that an x windows session is not created/attached for the other users, but don't know how to verify/fix this.

Comment: Instead of using VNC in such a way where the security is disabled.  Just make the human element.  Just use a username and password that everyone will understand, like,`username`for the username and `password` for the password

Comment: @Ramhound the idea is to have it be as easy as possible (hence, no username/password to type in) and for every user to have his own account on the server.

Comment: If there is no password then each user having their account is pointless since every user would be able to access any other account they want.

Comment: That is correct, but not important. The point is they would each be working in their own space and their work would not impact the work of others.

Comment: with xrdp and tigervnc you could have persistent separate sessions for users, the connections would be made with remote desktop. Creating a set of user accounts with generated passwords and printing the login info should not take too much effort. Arranging 'their own space' other way could be difficult.